# Weird behaiviour onsubmit react-bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap but I am noticing some weird behavior on form submit.

I have a sign-in file which is a form in a modal

```
        <Modal>  
        ...
          <Form
            className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column"
            onSubmit={onSubmitSignIn}
          >
            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                className={`signInputStyle ${
                  invalidEmail ? "invalidFieldStyle" : ""
                }`}
                value={email}
                onChange={handleEmailValidation}
                required
              />
              <div>
                <small className="errorFormText">
                  {invalidEmail ? "must be a valid email" : ""}
                </small>
              </div>
            </Form.Group>
           ...
            <div className="signupAcc">
              Do not have an account?
              <span onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>SignUp</span>
              <SignUp show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false)} />
           </div>
         ...
       </Form>
      </Modal>
```

In the sign-in component when you click on the SignUp span, it displays the second modal(which is for sign-up, therefore I have two modals now).

The sign-up modal has a form that is similar to that of the sign-in and they both have onSubmit function.

```
      <Modal>  
        ...
         <Form
            className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column"
            onSubmit={onSubmitValue}
          >
            <Form.Group controlId="formGridFirstName1">
              <Form.Control
                placeholder="First Name"
                required
                name="firstname"
                className={`signInputStyle ${
                  invalidateField.firstname ? "invalidFieldStyle" : ""
                }`}
                onChange={handleUserInput}
              />
              <div>
                <small className="errorFormText">
                  {invalidateField.firstname
                    ? "must be at least three letters"
                    : ""}
                </small>
              </div>
            </Form.Group>
         ...
       </Form>
      </Modal>
```

I noticed when I clicked on the button(type='submit') for the sign-up file it also triggers the onSubmit for the sign-in. My question is why is this behavior? Is it because both form fields are in the dom already? or something else? I really want to know the reason behind this behavior and how to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is just native HTML `button` behaviour. As stated on the [documentation](https://html.com/attributes/button-type/), the button element contains the `type` attribute accepts 3 values: `submit`, `reset`, and `button`. If the `type` attribute is supplied with the `submit` value, it will

> Submit the current form data.

Deep inside the hood of, React-bootstrap's `Form` Components, it probably makes use of the HTML [Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) Element, hence clicking on the button triggers the same mechanism for [Form.submit()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp).

If you do not want this behaviour, you may simply remove the `type` attribute ,or set the type attribute aas button (`type="button"`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but if I change the type attribute of the button to something else I won't be able to get the default Html validation.

Comment: @CharlesLukes Ahh I see.. In that case, do you mind posting the code for the button? In general, if you want to keep the `type` as submit, one way to prevent the button from firing Form.submit() would be to use event.preventDefault() on the onclick event. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 0):

Make one of the buttons as type="button" and add an onClick action. the other one should work this way.